# zabbix テストメール送信の際のエラー（SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input）について

Tags: linux, zabbix

zabbixのWeb画面上で、メディアタイプ設定のところからテストメールを送信しようとしたところ、
次の内容のポップアップが表示され、メールを送信することができません。
「SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input」

何か、設定が必要なのでしょうか。

現状、zabbixで監視対象を監視できるように構築は完了していますが、
メールのための構築は何もしておらず、zabbix画面上でSMTPサーバーの設定をしているのみです。
何か、Linuxサーバーで必要な設定があるようでしたらご教授お願いします。

環境
・CentOS8stream
・Zabbix6.0

Answer (score 0):

メール送信を行うには、有効な SMTP サーバを指定する必要があるようなので確認してください。

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/jp/manual/config/notifications/media/email

Comment: 有効なSMTPサーバを指定しているのですが、テストメールを送ろうとすると、上記のメッセージが出てくるのです